# get back to users datagridview selection after selecting all programmatically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

In order to speed up the export of data held in a datagridview to excel, I am using a method suggest in this forum where the contents of the datagridview are copied to the clipboard, and then pasted into the excel spreadsheet, in order to cut down on the amount of times the application has to communicate with excel.

Whilst this works fine, one draw back is that if a user has particular cells selected in the datagridview - the code will cause this selection to be lost, as it uses the `datagridview.SelectAll()` method.

I was hoping to find a simple solution to reselect the users original selection post exporting to excel. I have tried the following:

```
    Dim mySelection As DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection

    mySelection = myDataGridView.SelectedCells

    ExportToExcel(myDataGridView, "Exported Data")

    myDataGridView.SelectedCells = mySelection
```

I suspect that `DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection` is not the correct thing to use here, as it seems to be about the data held within the selection rather than the positions of the selected cells.

Alternative is there a way of getting all of the datagridview into the clipboard without having to use `SelectAll()`?

If needed the Export to Excel code is here:

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel(myDataGridView As DataGridView, myWorksheetName As String)

    ' Creating a Excel object.
    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing

    Try

        xlWorkSheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

        xlWorkSheet.Name = myWorksheetName


        'Data transfer from grid to Excel.  
        With xlWorkSheet
            .Range("1:1").EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
            'Set Clipboard Copy Mode     
            myDataGridView.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText
            myDataGridView.SelectAll()

            'Get the content from Grid for Clipboard     
            Dim str As String = TryCast(myDataGridView.GetClipboardContent().GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText), String)

            'Set the content to Clipboard     
            Clipboard.SetText(str, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText)

            'Identify and select the range of cells in Excel to paste the clipboard data.     
            .Range("A1").Select()

            'Paste the clipboard data     
            .Paste()
            Clipboard.Clear()
        End With

        'Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
        Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
        saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
        saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2

        If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)
            MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        excel.Quit()
        workbook = Nothing
        excel = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells(v=vs.110).aspx), the SelectedCells property is read only, and therefore, as you said, not the correct thing to use. To suggest an appropriate alternative, I expect that we will need to see the code for `ExportToExcel()`

Comment: I've added this - the key point as I mentioned in the original question, is the fact that the the export code uses `myDataGridView.SelectAll()` to add the contents of the datagridview to the clipboard, thus overwriting the users selection.

Comment: As I see it, you can either 1) Try to reselect the cells again (as in soohoonigan's answer), or 2) change your export logic to something that does not depend on cell selection, such as iterating through the cells, appending the value to a StringBuilder, and then copying that text to the clipboard, or 3) Avoid the clipboard altogether by using a library or exporting a CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the contents of the `DataGridView` without changing the selection. Do this by assembling a tab-delimited unicode String and pushing it into the `ClipBoard`:

```
  Sub CopyDataGridViewToClipboard(dgv As DataGridView, includeHeader As Boolean)
    Dim sbl As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    If includeHeader Then
      For intCol As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim dgvc As DataGridViewColumn = dgv.Columns(intCol)
        If intCol > 0 Then sbl.Append(vbTab)
        sbl.Append(dgvc.HeaderText)
      Next intCol
      sbl.AppendLine()
    End If
    For intRow As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
      Dim dgvr As DataGridViewRow = dgv.Rows(intRow)
      For intCol As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
        If intCol > 0 Then sbl.Append(vbTab)
        sbl.Append(dgvr.Cells(intCol).Value)
      Next intCol
      sbl.AppendLine()
    Next intRow
    Clipboard.SetText(sbl.ToString, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText)
  End Sub
```

Comment: Whilst both solutions work - I have chosen this as the answer, as it avoids the user ever seeing their selection change, and thus the whole export process feels less "clunky".

Answer (score 1):

Since DGV.SelectedCells is readonly, I think you may just have to set each cell's selected property to true individually (unless you're doing full row/column selection). You could just iterate through your Selected Cells Collection, and reselect each one:

```
myDataGridView.ClearSelection()
If mySelection IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each dgvCell As DataGridViewCell In mySelection
        dgvCell.Selected = True
    Next
    mySelection = Nothing
End If
```